# How to add a existing Database to a Web-Api in C#

Tags: c#, api, http

i need to create a Web-Api in C# which is connected with an existing database. I succesfully created the Web-Api but i am struggling to connect it to my database.

What is the best procedure?

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the API created I assume you also have the context created for it as well (if using Entity Framework).

Underneath `appsettings.json` you can add a connections string like so:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": 
     "#Connection String Here#"
   }
 }
```

Then you can reference this connection through your `startup.cs` under ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDbContext<#YourContext#>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
```

That above code assumes you will also be using SQL Server. It will be different depending on which type of server you will be connecting to.

Comment: Thank you very much. But where can I find the ConnectionString of my Database?

Comment: That depends on what you are using or if you have software already connected to it. But, for example, if you are already connected to it through Visual studio you can pull it up through View -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> (Right-Click Database) -> Properties -> Connection string.